# How to make an insert form and a table displaying data from database in a single view in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreach, view, datatable, insert

I'm making a CRUD but I want the create and read parts to be in a single MVC view. The create part is done, I've been trying to fill an HTML table with data from a database table when the view loads, but it won't let me do both things at once in a single view.

Here's the view header:

```
@model Console.Models.Product
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
```

Here's the insert form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.Hidden("productID", 0)
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.productName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @name = "txtProductName", @id = "txtProductName" } })
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.productName, "", new { @class = "text-danger", Type = "productName" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.productQuantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @name = "txtProductQuantity", @id = "txtProductQuantity" } })
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.productQuantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.productColor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @name = "txtProductColor", @id = "txtProductColor" } })
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.productColor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

This is the table that should show the products that are inserted into the database in the form above:

```
<table id="Data_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.productName)
            </th>
            <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.productQuantity)
            </th>
            <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.productColor)
            </th>
            <th>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.productName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.productQuantity)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.productColor)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.productID }, new { @class = "btn btn-success btn-sm" }) 
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.productID }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th><div class="panel-footer">Total = @Model.Count()</div></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Problem is that I get an error at the foreach telling me to use `IEnumerable` with the model but whenever I do, the insert form gets an error. Is there any way to get around this?

Edit:
Here's the view model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Console.Models
{
    public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public int productID{ get; set; }

        public string productName{ get; set; }

        public int productQuantity{ get; set; }

        public string productColor{ get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view you do pass a single model, and then you try to iterate over it, that of course is not possible.

You should use view models. Create a view model that contains both the fields you need for the form and the list of products you want to iterate over on foreach.

```
@model ProductViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
```

Create a view model, like this:

```
public class ProductViewModel {
     public string ProductName { get; set; }
     // Other fields for the form

     public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; } // Your list of products for the table
}
```

And then in your view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName,
// Continue with the form

@foreach (var item in Model.Products)
{ //...continue with your table
```

Comment: I'm now getting an error at the foreach of the table that says "Product" does not contain a definiton for "Products" nor an accesible extension method for "Products" that accepts an argument of the type "Product", even though it is defined in the view model?

Comment: Can you add your view model to your original answer so I can check it?

Comment: Ok, I just edited the original question to include it, thank you for your time.

Comment: Also I did modify the view header to @model Console.Models.ProductViewModel but if I understand the error message correctly, visualstudio still doesn't detect it for some reason?